# Why is it sometimes less expensive to fly an extra leg?

Tags: air-travel

Noticed that if I book a flight from SYdney to Vancouver, it costs $1014. But if I book a flight from Sydney to LA via Vancouver, it's only $632.

See screenshots below. It's literally the same flight and journey. But if I get off at Vancouver it'll cost more than I took another flight to LA?

[image]

[image]

How are flight prices worked out that would cause this to happen? I thought the cost would just be the sum of all the flights you are going to take?

Could I simply get to Vancouver and decide not to board my LA flight?